# Postfix/Dovecot: Thunderbird can't move to sent

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, thunderbird

I have a small mail server set up using postfix and dovecot. All is well; I have proper certificates, multiple isolated users, etc.

However, when sending a message from Thunderbird I get an error: "There was an error saving the message to Sent Messages. Retry?". I have tried all of dovecot's mail storage configurations, but the error persisted. What am I overlooking?

I suspect it has something to do with the ability of the client to create new folders over IMAP, but I wouldn't know how to grant clients that ability.

As for the nature of my system: I basically followed [this tutorial](https://appbead.com/blog/how-to-setup-mail-server-on-debian-8-jessie-with-postfix-dovecot-1.html), but on Debian 9.

Comment: 'I followed this tutorial' is never helpful. We have no way to know which steps you did and which you skipped (doesn't matter if on purpose or by accident) or changed while trying to get it running. Edit your actual configuration files in the question along with error messages that most probably are shown in the error log on your server when you try to send the message.

Comment: Try adding the output of `dovecot -n` to your post.  Ensure it is displayed as pre-formatted text.

Comment: You need to indicate if you are using Maildir or not, where the mail spool is located, how it is structured, the ownership of the mbox or Maildir files, etc.  There are many things that could go wrong, but if I would guess, and assuming it is a Maildir (or similar) setup, it is probably a file permissions issue on the server.

Comment: My guess would be file system permissions denying the creation of the "Sent Messages" folder, but it is impossible to tell without the doveconf output or some information on the filesystem.  The content of the dovecot error log would also be instructive.